# Commons Net FTPClient passiveHost has a wrong ip address due to natting

Tags: java, ssl, nat, apache-commons-net, ftps

I am using apache commons.net 3.5 and am trying to make a passive FTPES connection from behind a (masquerading) NAT box. BIG-IP(F5). The external FTP server doesn't support [EPSV](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2013/07/04/a-network-analysis-of-passive-epsv-or-pasv-ftp-connection/).

The problem I have is that I can't setup a data-channel because the control channel returns 'Entering passive mode (213,43,13,53,27,149)'. Without EPSV I have no option in the commons.net FTPClient to ignore the returning ip-address and force it to use the same ip-address as the control channel.

[image: Graphical example of the connection problem]

The the method '*_openDataConnection(String, String)*' method in the FTPClient uses the variable '**__passiveHost**' which is set by the method '**_parsePassiveModeReply**'. I would like to override this or maybe force it to keep the original ip-address from the control-channel.

*Code from Apache Commons Net added for reference.*

**_openDataConnection in org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient:**

```
 protected Socket _openDataConnection_(String command, String arg)
throws IOException
{
    if (__dataConnectionMode != ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE &&
            __dataConnectionMode != PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE) {
        return null;
    }

    final boolean isInet6Address = getRemoteAddress() instanceof Inet6Address;

    Socket socket;

    if (__dataConnectionMode == ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE)
    {
        // if no activePortRange was set (correctly) -> getActivePort() = 0
        // -> new ServerSocket(0) -> bind to any free local port
        ServerSocket server = _serverSocketFactory_.createServerSocket(getActivePort(), 1, getHostAddress());

        try {
            // Try EPRT only if remote server is over IPv6, if not use PORT,
            // because EPRT has no advantage over PORT on IPv4.
            // It could even have the disadvantage,
            // that EPRT will make the data connection fail, because
            // today's intelligent NAT Firewalls are able to
            // substitute IP addresses in the PORT command,
            // but might not be able to recognize the EPRT command.
            if (isInet6Address) {
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(eprt(getReportHostAddress(), server.getLocalPort()))) {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(port(getReportHostAddress(), server.getLocalPort()))) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            if ((__restartOffset > 0) && !restart(__restartOffset)) {
                return null;
            }

            if (!FTPReply.isPositivePreliminary(sendCommand(command, arg))) {
                return null;
            }

            // For now, let's just use the data timeout value for waiting for
            // the data connection.  It may be desirable to let this be a
            // separately configurable value.  In any case, we really want
            // to allow preventing the accept from blocking indefinitely.
            if (__dataTimeout >= 0) {
                server.setSoTimeout(__dataTimeout);
            }
            socket = server.accept();

            // Ensure the timeout is set before any commands are issued on the new socket
            if (__dataTimeout >= 0) {
                socket.setSoTimeout(__dataTimeout);
            }
            if (__receiveDataSocketBufferSize > 0) {
                socket.setReceiveBufferSize(__receiveDataSocketBufferSize);
            }
            if (__sendDataSocketBufferSize > 0) {
                socket.setSendBufferSize(__sendDataSocketBufferSize);
            }
        } finally {
            server.close();
        }
    }
    else
    { // We must be in PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE

        // Try EPSV command first on IPv6 - and IPv4 if enabled.
        // When using IPv4 with NAT it has the advantage
        // to work with more rare configurations.
        // E.g. if FTP server has a static PASV address (external network)
        // and the client is coming from another internal network.
        // In that case the data connection after PASV command would fail,
        // while EPSV would make the client succeed by taking just the port.
        boolean attemptEPSV = isUseEPSVwithIPv4() || isInet6Address;
        if (attemptEPSV && epsv() == FTPReply.ENTERING_EPSV_MODE)
        {
            _parseExtendedPassiveModeReply(_replyLines.get(0));
        }
        else
        {
            if (isInet6Address) {
                return null; // Must use EPSV for IPV6
            }
            // If EPSV failed on IPV4, revert to PASV
            if (pasv() != FTPReply.ENTERING_PASSIVE_MODE) {
                return null;
            }
            _parsePassiveModeReply(_replyLines.get(0));
        }

        socket = _socketFactory_.createSocket();
        if (__receiveDataSocketBufferSize > 0) {
            socket.setReceiveBufferSize(__receiveDataSocketBufferSize);
        }
        if (__sendDataSocketBufferSize > 0) {
            socket.setSendBufferSize(__sendDataSocketBufferSize);
        }
        if (__passiveLocalHost != null) {
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(__passiveLocalHost, 0));
        }

        // For now, let's just use the data timeout value for waiting for
        // the data connection.  It may be desirable to let this be a
        // separately configurable value.  In any case, we really want
        // to allow preventing the accept from blocking indefinitely.
        if (__dataTimeout >= 0) {
            socket.setSoTimeout(__dataTimeout);
        }

        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(__passiveHost, __passivePort), connectTimeout);
        if ((__restartOffset > 0) && !restart(__restartOffset))
        {
            socket.close();
            return null;
        }

        if (!FTPReply.isPositivePreliminary(sendCommand(command, arg)))
        {
            socket.close();
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (__remoteVerificationEnabled && !verifyRemote(socket))
    {
        socket.close();

        throw new IOException(
                "Host attempting data connection " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() +
                " is not same as server " + getRemoteAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    return socket;
}
```

**_parsePassiveModeReply in org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient:**

```
 protected void _parsePassiveModeReply(String reply)
throws MalformedServerReplyException
{
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = __PARMS_PAT.matcher(reply);
    if (!m.find()) {
        throw new MalformedServerReplyException(
                "Could not parse passive host information.\nServer Reply: " + reply);
    }

    __passiveHost = m.group(1).replace(',', '.'); // Fix up to look like IP address

    try
    {
        int oct1 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        int oct2 = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        __passivePort = (oct1 << 8) | oct2;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        throw new MalformedServerReplyException(
                "Could not parse passive port information.\nServer Reply: " + reply);
    }

    if (__passiveNatWorkaround) {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(__passiveHost);
            // reply is a local address, but target is not - assume NAT box changed the PASV reply
            if (host.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                InetAddress remote = getRemoteAddress();
                if (!remote.isSiteLocalAddress()){
                    String hostAddress = remote.getHostAddress();
                    fireReplyReceived(0,
                                "[Replacing site local address "+__passiveHost+" with "+hostAddress+"]\n");
                    __passiveHost = hostAddress;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) { // Should not happen as we are passing in an IP address
            throw new MalformedServerReplyException(
                    "Could not parse passive host information.\nServer Reply: " + reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for trying to help me. The only solution I currently see is copying the Apache Commons FTP code and implementing my own changes to make it work with a masquerading NAT box.

Comment: As I can not add any more links:
Other people have also an issue with this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-588